# HTML, CSS Shape and Button Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have the below *working example* which needs editing:

I want the red square to be centre aligned above table 1 & 2.
I then want the black dots to be aligned left vertically (one on top of the order) but left of the red square. What is the **best way** to achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/2mv98mkp/6/

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
  <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
  <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/B/J/j/R/red-square-th.png'>
</div>
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.redsquare {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100px;
}
.redsquare>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -70px;
  width: 70px;
}
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="redsquare">
    <div class="dots">
      <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
      <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
    </div>
    <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/B/J/j/R/red-square-th.png'>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3ozmqhq8

I added a `position: absolute` to the dots, and then I centered the square using `margin: 0 auto` and `display:block`.

If you don't want to change `display`, you can apply to `.cnt` this: `text-align:center` since `img` is a line element, it will be centered.

```css
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cnt {
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

#c1,
#c2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0
}

#c2 {
  left: 45px
}

#square {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <img id="c1" src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
  <img id="c2" src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
  <img id="square" src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/B/J/j/R/red-square-th.png'>
</div>
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

**Try this:** https://jsfiddle.net/3ozmqhq8/2/

And if you want to center the dots you can move them to the right increasing `left` in `#c1` and `#c2`

Comment: Ok this is looking good. I just want the buttons vertically aligned on the left.

Comment: replace *#c1,
#c2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0
} #c2{left:45px}* with *#c1{position:absolute; top:20px; left:0}
#c2{position:absolute; top:60px; left:0}*

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code if it helps you:

```css
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.images-area {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.red-square {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.black-circles {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -60px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
}

.black-circles img {
  margin: 0 0 -15px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-area">
  <div class="black-circles">
      <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
      <img src='http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/black_circle.png'>
  </div>
  <img class="red-square" src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/B/J/j/R/red-square-th.png'>
</div>
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```